# Flask static images not loading

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

So I'm trying to set an image as the background of a page in CSS but Flask isn't loading the image correctly. `background.jpg` is located in `static/images`.

```css
background: url("{{ url_for('static', filename='images/background.jpg') }}");
```

```
"GET /static/stylesheets/%7B%7B%20url_for('static',%20filename='images/background.jpg')%20%7D%7D HTTP/1.1" 404
```

My server file:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder = "pages", static_folder="static")


@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("home.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, threaded=True, port=80)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your CSS is in a different file from the HTML template and so isn't being parsed when the HTML file is rendered.

I think this may be the case as the 404 error appears to have the unparsed text in the URL, plus if I take your example, but embed the CSS statement directly into a style tag then it works as expected, e.g.

```
<div style='background: url("{{ url_for("static", filename="images/background.jpg") }}")'></div>
```

Obviously to fix this issue you can either embed the CSS directly into the HTML element as shown above, or in a `<style>` block in the HTML template file.

Comment: The background wasn't displayed, but it did load correctly with code 200.

Comment: Nevermind. Sorry, I accidentally pasted this in the wrong place. It works now! But is there any way to set the background inside the CSS file?

Comment: There's no explicit way that I know. Off the top of my head, you could try pointing your <LINK> to an @app.route endpoint which then renders a CSS file. No idea if that would actually work and seems quite contrived for a scenario where the path/filename is normally static in any case.

Answer (score 1):

render_template("home.html") renders only html file. Css will be rendered only if it is in html file in "< style >" tag. If its external file flask won't do anything with it.

Comment: I have added the CSS file using by using `url_for` in the link tag. The CSS is displaying correctly, but the image isn't.

Comment: @InfiniteVortex32 url_for creates a dynamic URL to your CSS file, but it does not cause Flask to run that target file through the parser.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that it's not loading the image because CSS files are read as static files, so you should not be using the ***url_for*** method in your CSS if your file structure is:

```
static
  -images
  -css
```

Use only background-image: `url( images/background.jpg )`

Comment: Now it's trying to fetch `/static/stylesheets/images/background.jpg` which is not the correct path.